# How to check the history of a particular session in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle database 19c. I need to identify the historical blocking session details which had blocked almost 50 sessions. In ASH report, i can find the sid **1258** under blocking_session column under `dba_hist_active_sess_history` but not under sid column which is pretty unusual. I could not find any information related to activity of blocking session from hang analyze report as well. Is there any way to drill down the depth of a session other than ASH?

**dba_hist_active_sess_history output**

```
SAMPLE_ID SAMPLE TIME   SID STATE         EVENT                     SQL_ID             BLK SID START SQL_EXEC_ID

---------- ----------- ----- ------------- ------------------------- --------------- ---------- ----- -----------

135345711 21 11:25:11   217 WAITING       enq: TX - row lock conten shd23fhjdgjyhu         1258 <<== blocking sid 21:04    19783669
```

**Hang analyze output**:

```
 {
                      p1: 'driver id'=0x54435000
                      p2: '#bytes'=0x1
            time in wait: 2 min 16 sec
           timeout after: never
                 wait id: 1445
                blocking: 1 session
          current sql_id: 3598363420
```

Thanks in advance !